# How to develop responsive layer container in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, layers, react

I'm using leaflet.js to develop a drawing layer tool with the full-page map. Users will draw a group of layers to describe an industrial product's parts.

The leaflet map and its layers should be fit to screen. For example, if a user draws a circle to the left bottom corner with 1920x1080 resolution pc, I should see it in the left bottom corner with my 1366x768 resolution pc. The leaflet map is resizing with the page correctly but the circle is being out of the screen in my pc because of its latitude-longitude in this example.

I tried to develop this example with invalidateSize, maxBounds, fitBounds, etc. but haven't succeeded yet. How can I develop this scenario?

[image: Saved GeoJSON from 1920x1080 with layers looking:]

[image: Loaded same GeoJSON from 1366x768 looking (attention to left corner):]

Map (React):

```
  const corner1 = L.latLng(-180, -180);
  const corner2 = L.latLng(180, 180);
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2);

        <Map
        ref={map => {
          this.tryToCreate(map);
        }}
        className="c-leaflet-map-map"
        center={[0, 0]}
        zoom={0}
        maxZoom={10}
        zoomControl={false}
        onzoomend={this.zoomLevelsChange}
        maxBounds={bounds}
        maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
        zoomSnap={0}
        crs={L.CRS.Simple}
      >
        <ImageOverlay
          bounds={map.backgroundImageBounds || map.bounds}
          attribution="&amp;copy TofnaTech"
          url={
            map.backgroundImage ||
            map.backgroundImageURL ||
            TransparentImage
          }
          opacity={map.opacity}
          className={cn({ transparentImage: !map.backgroundImage })}
        />
        <FeatureGroup
          ref={controller => {
            this.controller = controller;
            this.tryToCreate();
          }}
        >
          <EditControl
            position="topleft"
            onCreated={this._onCreated}
            onEditStart={this.onEditStart}
            onEditStop={this.onEditStop}
            onEdited={this.onEdited}
            draw={{
              polyline: false,
              polygon: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              rectangle: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              circle: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              marker: false,
              circlemarker: false
            }}
            edit={{
              remove: false
            }}
          /></Map>
```